# gsub is not substituting links in R

Tags: r, gsub

Hi guys I am trying to do something simple. For some reason gsub is being a jerk.

```
vector <- c("http://aa.bb.com/ss/who/searchpage/tab/message?sort_by=-topicPostDate&page=YOU","http://aa.bb.com/ss/who/searchpage/tab/message?filter=labels location&location=oh-my:DID IT","BLAH BLAH")


subs <- c("http://aa.bb.com/ss/who/searchpage/tab/message?sort_by=-topicPostDate&page=",
          "http://aa.bb.com/ss/who/searchpage/tab/message?filter=labels location&location=oh-my:")

gsub(paste(subs,collapse = "|"),"",vector, fixed = TRUE)
```

What I am trying to say with gsub is replace item 1 or item 2 in `sub` with "" if found in vector.
Anyone? It doesn't have to involve gsub. I just want a line of code that says replace if you see this or that or this with "" in a vector of strings.

Comment: When you set `fixed=T` the `|` is interpreted as part of the pattern string.

Comment: Removed it. Still no luck.

Comment: So I am guessing this is because when I removed it, it started interpreting special characters.

Comment: Removing the `|` will not help - now the pattern is just the concatenation of the two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `|` to mean "OR" in regular expressions, you need `fixed=F`.

However, the `?` in your patterns mean something to: one or zero occurrence of the character before, instead of matching a literal `?` as you want.

One way to work around is to escape the `?` in `subs`:

```
subs <- gsub('?', '\\?', subs, fixed=T)
gsub(paste(subs,collapse = "|"), "", vector, fixed=F)
# [1] "YOU"       "DID IT"    "BLAH BLAH"
```